# spring boot gateway with eureka server

Tags: spring, microservices, gateway

iam using spring boot gateway with eureka server but when i try to reach  some api from gateway it dose not take the path of gateway route it takes the service name

```
@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {

        @Bean
        public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
            return builder.routes()
                    
                //  .route("book", r -> r.path("/book/**").uri("lb://BOOKS"))
    
                    .route("bookstore", r -> r.path("/booksstore/**").uri("lb://BOOKSTORE"))
                     .route("book",
                                r -> r.path("/book/**")
                              
                                        .uri("lb://BOOKS"))
                
                    .build();
        }
    
    }
```

[not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWuRm.jpg)

but if i replace "book" with "books" (service name) it will work

Answer (score 1):

According to your configuration, api-gateway by URI "lb://BOOKS" gets from eureka server the path to your service "http://ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх:8080/", and your service seems to have an endpoint "/books", not "/book".

Accordingly, you need to change the endpoint in your remote service to "/book".